# Listview - Multi column - Change selection color for the whole row

Tags: vb.net, listview, colors, selection

I would like to change selection color in a ListView, from a default (blue). I can not adapt any code that I found to my needs.

Here is the code that is closest.

```
  If e.Item.Selected = True Then
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.Gray), e.Bounds)
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Item.Text, New Font(ListView2.Font, Nothing), New Point(e.Bounds.Left + 3, e.Bounds.Top + 2), Color.White)
    Else
        e.DrawDefault = True
    End If
```

The main problem is `e.Item.Text` part. It doesn't work for multi column listview. Here is the result.

Before selection :
[image]

...and after : 
[image]

Is it possible to preserve values from other columns and still have full row selection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to keep in mind with an OwnerDraw `Listview` is that there are **2 events** to respond to (or override if you are subclassing) if the control is Details `View`: `DrawColumnHeader` and `DrawSubItem`.

`DrawItem` would be used when the control is using a different `View` and there are no SubItems to draw.

Since `SubItems(0)` is the same as `Item.Text`, you can use `DrawSubItem` to draw the item and subitem text.  I cannot tell where that snippet is located, but this will work:

```
Private Sub lv1_DrawSubItem(sender As Object, 
       e As DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs) Handles lv1.DrawSubItem

    ' use sender instead of a hardcodes control ref so 
    ' you can paste this to another LV
    Dim myLV As ListView = CType(sender, ListView)

    If e.ItemIndex > 0 AndAlso e.Item.Selected Then
        Using br As New SolidBrush(Color.Gray)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.Bounds)
        End Using

        Using fnt As New Font(myLV .Font, Nothing)
        ' use e.SubItem.Text
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.SubItem.Text,
                          fnt,
                          New Point(e.Bounds.Left + 3, e.Bounds.Top + 2),
                          Color.White)
        End Using     ' dispose!
    Else
        e.DrawDefault = True
    End If

End Sub
```

It would appear that you may be using the correct event, but by using`Item.Text` rather than `e.SubItem.Text` the Item text will be also be drawn for all SubItems (`DrawSubItem` will be called as many times as there are subitems).

Note that I also wrapped the `Font` in a `Using` block to dispose of it.  Using LimeGreen, the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Plutonix, you helped me alot.