# Dynamically coloring listview but only one column is the text being colored

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

I used listview for my winform and ran in to a problem where the highlighted color was so light once the control lost focus that you could not see it. The text is not showing in the second column.

I found a blog that showed that you could color it yourself and have the last selected item show in the color you want.

This is my listview when I have `OwnerDraw` set to false:

[image]

You can see the 2nd column on this one.

This is what it looks like when I have `OwnerDraw` set to true:

[image]

While using this code:

```
  Private Sub lvModelsInfo_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DrawListViewItemEventArgs)
    If e.Item.Selected Then
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.LightBlue), e.Bounds)
      e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, ListView1.Font, New SolidBrush(Color.Black), e.Bounds.Location)

    Else
      e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, ListView1.Font, New SolidBrush(Color.Black), e.Bounds.Location)
    End If
  End Sub
```

I've not worked with e.Graphics before. If I had to guess, I would think it had to do with the `e.Bounds` but I'm not sure.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Both images show 2 columns being colored, so what is the problem?  Also the result seems to match the code.  (You should probably use `sender` in place of hardcoding `ListView1` though)

Comment: `e.Bounds` is the rectangle use to color the `ListViewItem`

Comment: @Plutonix sorry, I wasn't clear. I have updated the question. I meant the second columns' text is not being set to black on the second image.

Comment: @OneFineDay How do I extend that out to get both columns?

Comment: you are using the wrong event - use `DrawSubItem` with no code there there is nothing to draw the subitems. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29805936/1070452